# how do I run code after the last element has completed its jQuery slideup effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

If I have a .slideUp() that runs against a class that belongs to multiple elements, how do I run code after the *last* element has completed its slideup effect? It seems like using the built in complete callback runs the callback after every individual element completes its slideup instead of doing it once when theyre all complete.

Here's some example code that might help illustrate the issue I'm having:

```js
$("#my-button").click(() => {
  $(".my-target-class").slideUp(400, () => {
    console.log("I only want this to fire once...");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="my-target-class">div 1</div>
    <div class="my-target-class">div 2</div>
    <div class="my-target-class">div 3</div>
    <button id="my-button">try me</button>
</section>
```

Comment: These both provide suitable solutions, thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, this will actually run your `slideUp` (*including* its callback) on all elements, so the callback also fires several times.

You can use `.promise` to get a promise for the whole operation, and react on it being `done`:

```js
$("#my-button").click(() => {
  $(".my-target-class").slideUp(400).promise().done(() => {
    console.log("I only want this to fire once...");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="my-target-class">div 1</div>
    <div class="my-target-class">div 2</div>
    <div class="my-target-class">div 3</div>
    <button id="my-button">try me</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! I also found that using $.when(...).then(...); worked as per the links you and XCS provided as comments on my original question. In 5 min when I'm allowed to do it I'll checkmark this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should containerize the divs and only slide that one up:

```js
$("#my-button").click(() => {
  $(".target-container").slideUp(400, () => {
    console.log("I only want this to fire once...");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="target-container">
    <div class="my-target-class">div 1</div>
    <div class="my-target-class">div 2</div>
    <div class="my-target-class">div 3</div>
  </div>
  <button id="my-button">try me</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Depends... it will look differently.

Comment: @CherryDT's answer is better for your issue.  It'd be my preference, at least.  I undeleted this answer because you're right, others may find value in it.

Comment: this is not suitable for the actual project I'm working on, unfortunately. Some of the elements with this class need to be visible when others aren't. However, CherryDT's answer worked. For other people who are able to structure their code in this way without losing functionality, this is absolutely a more intuitive solution.

Comment: Removed my copy of it now.